# Confusing with list by proving of linearly independence.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I started the chapter 2 of the book "Linear Algebra Done Right" by Sheldon Axler. He says: "To avoid confusion, we will usually write lists of vectors without surrounding parentheses". For example $(4,1,6), (9,5,7)$ is list of lenght 2 of vectors in $\mathbb R$.

I understand it so: if $v_1,v_2...v_m$ is list of vectors in, for example, $\mathbb R^5$, then I image it so:

$v_1=(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4,x_5),v_2=(y_1,y_2,y_3,y_4,y_5)....v_m=(z_1,z_2,z_3,z_4,z_5)$. So we have list of lenght $m$ and every vector has 5 coordinates.

In exercises 2. A (5)

(a) Show that if we think of $\mathbb C$ as a vector space of $\mathbb R$, then the list $(1+i,1-i)$ is linearly independent.

The first question is: Do we have now the list of lenght 1 (because we have only 1 vector in list, that has 2 coordinates)?

If yes, then I am confusing with the solution I found.

$\textbf{Solution:}$ Let $x,y \in \mathbb R$, then if $x(1+i)+y(1-i)=0$ then we have $$0=x(1+i)+y(1-i)=(x+y)+(x-y)i$$
hence $x+y=0$ and $x-y=0$ it follows $x=y=0$. Thus the list $(1+i,1-i)$ is linearly independent over $\mathbb R$.

I can't understand how we can write it: $x(1+i)+y(1-i)=0$??

For example, we take $v_1=(1,2)$. This vector has the same structure as vector above. So it's list of lenght 1 with 2 coordinates. Now if I want to prove linearly independence of this vector, I have to prove that $$a\cdot v_1=0$$ is possible only for $a=0$.

$a\cdot v_1=a\cdot (1,2)=(a,2a)$, so $(a\cdot 1,a\cdot 2)=(0\cdot 1,0 \cdot 2)$, it follows,that $a=0$.

So the main question is: Where did this form $x(1+i)+y(1-i)$ come from?

If $v:=(1+i,1-i)$, then I must prove that $$a\cdot v=0$$
$a\cdot (1+i,1-i)=0$. Why there are 2 scalars in solution above $x,y$ instead of 1 ?

Can somebody explain me it?

Comment: (a) Axler is talking about the real vector space $\mathbb{C}$, not $\mathbb{C}^2$. The list has length 2.

Comment: @MatthewTowers so we have two vectors, right? $v_1=(1+i)$ and $v_2=(1-i)$, is it what does he mean?

Comment: yes (but there's no need to write brackets round them)

Comment: @MatthewTowers at the beginning of the chapter, he says, that he will write lists of vectors without surrounding parentheses, but he made it 10 pages later. Thank you)

Comment: right but what I mean is that in your first comment you've put brackets round the individual vectors, not round the list, e.g. you wrote $v_1 = (1+i)$ but you could just say $v_1 = 1+i$.  Anyway it's not important.

Comment: @MatthewTowers yes, I understood it)

Comment: In that exercise, I meant for $1+i,1−i$ to be thought of as a list of length 2 in $\mathbf{C}$. I am sorry about the confusion caused by putting parentheses around that list. This issue has already been fixed in the forthcoming fourth edition of Linear Algebra Done Right.

Comment: @SheldonAxler is it really you ?) No problem, thank you for your book) It’s very helpful))